# How to measure the Sharpe Ratio of a high frequency trading strategy?

Tags: high-frequency, sharpe-ratio

The [Sharpe Ratio](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sharperatio.asp) is defined as `Sharpe ratio = (Mean portfolio return − Risk-free rate)/Standard deviation of portfolio return`.

Unfortunately, this does not make sense in the context of an HFT strategy. In order to calculate the return of a portfolio, you need to know the amount of capital deployed in an HFT strategy, which is not as straightforward as a portfolio of long/short stocks.

Should you calculate your return for an HFT strategy based on the margin posted for a specific strategy? Or is the inverse of the [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) `(AvgPnL / StdDev)` the best we can hope for?

Comment: I'd say avgPnL/stdPnL is fine

Comment: Thanks @LazyCat. Would you say targeting similar values in the Investopedia article makes sense? I.e., 1=ok, 2=good, 3+=excellent?

Comment: I'd say the values should be higher, e.g. 3-4 is good, but not excellent, but it depends on a strategy and what exactly you call HFT..

Comment: Agreed. Just double checking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **daily P&L** rather than return rate<sup>1</sup>.

$$ Sharpe = \frac{\mu}{\sigma} $$

To annualize, multiply by the square root of the number of trading days in the year. For US equities, that would be 252.

$$ Annualized\ Sharpe = \frac{\mu}{\sigma} \times \sqrt{252} $$

As for what kind of Sharpe you should target, the lowest I've seen is 5 in practice. A good strategy is more like 8, and the highest end goes into the double digits. The consistency of HFT is incomparable to every other kind of trading strategy.

<sup>1</sup><sub>In practice, I've never seen returns used to compute the Sharpe, even in low-frequency stat-arb strategies. Also, I've never seen anyone remove the risk-free rate, even if that's what every textbook states.</sub>